# How can I find out what time my hat was awarded?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

If I'm away from my keyboard I miss seeing the notification that I have received a new hat.

How can I found out what time it was awarded?

Knowing the (historical) hat award time would be useful when trying to work out triggers for the secret hats...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to directly see what time it was awarded.

You *can* see what time is was awarded relative to the other hats by seeing in what order they appear in the dropdown. For some hats, if you guess what action triggered it, you can often see when that action occurred on [your user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=all).

Comment: How about an indirect way? :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Other than making educated guesses, no.

Comment: Well there are time-based hats for a starter...

Comment: @PythonMaster Yeah, I assumed that was obvious.

Comment: Helpful information.